# How long does the descent of the Falcon 9 first stage take?

Tags: falcon-9, entry-descent-landing

After separating from the second stage, how long does it take for the Falcon 9 to come back to Earth?
From LEO and from GEO.

Note: this question is similar:
[How long does it take to recover the first stage of the Falcon 9?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-long-does-it-take-to-recover-the-first-stage-of-the-falcon-9)

Yet it's not clear the % of time taken for descent. How long to descend from GEO?

Comment: If you mean the first stage, it never goes into orbit at all. But there might be a difference in time depending on where the payload is ultimately headed.

Comment: "How long to descend from GEO?" – Infinitely, since it cannot get to GEO. (If it could, there would be no need for a second stage, after all.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will vary somewhat mission-to-mission, but it's generally about 6 minutes from separation to first-stage touchdown. It's not very different between LEO and GEO missions, as the first stage only gets to around 1/4 of orbital speed.

Here's the [timeline for ANASIS-II](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/07/20/falcon-9-launch-timeline-with-anasis-2/), a GEO-bound launch. Stage separation is at T+2:36 and first-stage touchdown is at T+8:31.

A [timeline for an LEO-bound Starlink launch](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/06/03/timeline-for-falcon-9-launch-with-starlink-satellites/) has separation at T+2:36 and touchdown at T+8:42.